# With `CarrierWave::MimeTypes` deprecated, how should uploaders handle/overwrite generic content types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, mime-types

## Problem

`CarrierWave::MimeTypes`, which added the `set_content_type` method to an uploader is deprecated. Among other things, [this method](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/mime_types.rb#L61) would attempt to detect the content type if the given one was generic (either `application/octet-stream` or `binary/octet-stream`).

The [deprecation message](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/mime_types.rb#L30) for `CarrierWave::MimeTypes` says:

> get the content_type from the SanitizedFile object directly

However this class always returns the existing content type if it is defined whether it is generic or not. [See the code here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb#L246).

## Current Solution

For now we're manually handling this by clearing the content type if it is a generic type and having the library then properly detect it. We could set it ourselves with a call to `::MIME::Types.type_for` however we're attempting to keep our code as upgrade compatible as we can.

## Question / tl;dr

Is there a best practice for handling CarrierWave uploads with generic content types (`application/octet-stream`) now that `CarrierWave::MimeTypes` is deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our existing solution is as follows for those who got here before we have anything better:

```
# we replicate this idea of generic types from CarrierWave::MimeTypes
GENERIC_CONTENT_TYPES = %w[application/octet-stream binary/octet-stream]

# and add a clearing method to our uploader processor
process :clear_generic_content_type

def clear_generic_content_type
  file.content_type = nil if GENERIC_CONTENT_TYPES.include?(file.try(:content_type))
end
```

Comment: I'd love to accept another answer if one comes around. For now this looks to be the best we can do until the next version hits.

Answer (score 2):

[Here on Carrierwave docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#setting-the-content-type) says that setting the content type is no longer needed:

> **Setting the content type**
>
> As of v0.11.0, the mime-types gem is a runtime dependency and the
>   content type is set automatically. You no longer need to do this
>   manually.

Comment: I'll try it here and check that everything is still working as expected.

Comment: this is true unless you using carrierwave_direct gem.  When you get the file back from S3 it will have the content_type of binary/octet-stream.  This raises hell when trying render the image in img tag or process versions.