# "uninitialized constant CarrierWave::MimeTypes" error with upgrade from 0.11.2 to 1.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, carrierwave

With carrierwave gem 1.1.0 in a vanilla Rails 5.1.4 app, I see this error in minitest:

```
NameError:  NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:6:in `<class:ImageUploader>'
  app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  app/models/image.rb:4:in `<class:Image>'
  app/models/image.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Previous posters [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1887) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905095/upgrading-from-carrierwave-0-11-2-to-1-0-breaks-uploads) suggest that removing these lines from the uploader will fix this:

```
include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
process :set_content_type
```

However although I've removed them, the error persists. Something else is going on.

With carrierwave gem 0.11.2, the exact same Rails application code causes no such error, so there is something broken or misconfigured moving from carrierwave 0.11.2 to 1.1.0.

Ideas/solutions? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Never mind. Turns out the problem was a bit of sheer idiocy on my part due to editing one Sublime Text 2 project and testing in an identically-named copy of the project. Removing those offending lines does indeed solve the problem.

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016316/with-carrierwavemimetypes-deprecated-how-should-uploaders-handle-overwrite